# modelformset_factory and on_delete=models.PROTECT

Tags: django, validation

My model has an `on_delete=models.PROTECT` constraing in a foreign key. When I try to remove referenced model through a modelformset_factory program crash:

> u'("Cannot delete some instances of model \'Zona\' because they are
>   referenced through a protected foreign key:
>   \'Camping.zonaTarifaria\'", [])'

I hoped that modelformset_factory handle the validation error like other validations, but not. Is there a magical solution?

I have tried to move error to a ValidationError in this way (in referenced model, of course):

```
class Zona(models.Model):
    codi = models.CharField(u'Codi', 
    ...

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super(Zona, self).delete( *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            raise ValidationError( e )
```

But it seems that modelformset_factory don't hand a validation error when comes from a delete method.

Comment: If you want the modelform to be aware of a ValidationError, you'd want to set it up in model cleaning, or better yet your modelform `clean()`. Unfortunately, I don't know how django tests cascade deletes. The admin code for the delete confirmation page would be a good place to look to emulate a dry-run cascade delete check. Otherwise, you'd be validating by attempting to do a post validated action (delete).

Comment: Thanks Yuji, I wrote my own workaround, but I'm looking for new approachs to get a more elegant solution.